# Error in displaying an image in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I am facing a problem in displaying images in php. The images are being stored in a table 'images' in mysql. There is another table 'restaurant' which needs to fetch those images and display respective images according to the restid. However, it is facing a problem in fetching the images and not displaying them. Please help!
This is imageupload.php:

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading image</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<form action='imageupload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Upload: <input type='file' name='image'><input type='submit' value='Upload' >
</form>";

if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))

{
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if($image_size==FALSE)
        echo "That's not an image";
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO images VALUES ('','$image_name','$image','22')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo "Problem uploading";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Image uploaded ";
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE restid = '22'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
            while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
            {
                header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
                echo $info['image'];
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    "Please upload a file";
}
 ?>
</body></html>
```

This is getimage.php (It fetches the image and displays it):

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$image = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imgid = $id" ;
$image = mysqli_query($con, $image);
$image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

connect.inc.php is a file to connect to the database. I referred to other links but did not get any solid help. Please provide help.

Comment: Why do you neet change header to display a image? The name save in images name is normal? Why do yo doesn't use `<img src="" />`?

Comment: Yes yes I tried the <img src="" /> but it displays the encrypted form of the image i.e. in the text form.

Comment: You save a custom image of image, a original name, or base64?

Comment: What you are trying to do in your second else branch is of course total nonsense – you can not output text first, and then serveral times a header followed by image data … and where and how you are using your getimage.php script, you haven’t even shown us.

Comment: Please learn to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY). In the current form your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing image in mysql should work.
Check that you don`t have any syntax errors. 
Temporary remove Content-type header to see that image file gets printed (as gibberish string). Also check that mysql field you store image is BLOB type.
Post if you have any error there.

Comment: I am getting the gibberish language when I remove the header and my image is stored as type BLOB... The error still persists.

Comment: I got it solved. Stored the path in database insted of the image itself.